# Laravel blade - set selected value if exists

Tags: php, select, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a form that can be used to submit and edit something. There are a few dropdown menus for which I want to set the selected value if the form is in edit mode. If the variable $holder -> year exists, it must print its value. Otherwise an empty value should be selected. I can't seem to fix this using the 'or' tag.

My code looks like this

```
'2013' => '2013',
'2014' => '2014',
'2015' => '2015'
),$holder-> year,
array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'year')
) }}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should add an empty value to your options array, something like:

```
['' => '-- Select year --']
```

And I assume your year parameter is representing a column in databse, that means if the column is empty, it returns as empty and should select the option I mentioned.